# Find computers in your local subnet using a specific software

Tags: networking, subnet

I am trying to make a software that would use computers in my local subnet who are also using the same software that I am making. Regarding this, I want to know how I should scan my device to find 1) devices in my local subnet, 2) devices in my local subnet that is using the software? Any idea on this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OS? Programming language?

For Windows and C#/VB you can use this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1(v=vs.110).aspx).

In general, all instances of your program should start *listeners* on some IP port.
Every listener waits a request, then sends an answer.
To locate all instances in local network your program must send *broadcast* request to the same port and wait for answers.

You can google example of UDP broadcasting for your platform (OS and programming language) for more details.